# Proving a function is uniformly continuous knowing that $\lim_{x\to 1^+} f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to 2^-} f(x)=3$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:(1,2)\longrightarrow{R}$ be a continuous function. We know that $\lim_{x\to 1^+} f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to 2^-} f(x)=3$.

How can I prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous? I don't think I can use the definition of uniformly continuity to solve it, and I dont know what to do with $\lim_{x\to 1^+} f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to 2^-} f(x)=3$

Comment: Did you mean uniformly continuous?

Comment: @Antoine Yes sorry, english is not my first language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every continuous function $g:[a, b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous. You can define 
$$
g(x) = 
\begin{cases}
f(x)& x\in (1, 2)\\
0 & x = 1\\
3 & x = 2
\end{cases}.
$$
Then, $f = g$ on the interval $(1,2)$. Now, since the two limits for your $f$ exist, you can prove that $g$ is continuous, thus  uniformly continuous function.

---

EDIT: How to prove that $g$ is continuous? As mentioend in the commen, by definition, $g$ is continuous in point $x$ if $g(x) = \lim_{x'\to x} g(x')$. Say $x = 1$. Since $g(x') = f(x')$ for $x\in (1,2)$, we have $$\lim_{x'\to 1} g(x') = \lim_{x'\to 1} f(x') = 0 = g(1)\text{,}$$
hence continuity in the point $x = 1$. Repeat this for $x = 2$.

Comment: I don't see how to prove $g$ is continuous either, could you explain it?

Comment: $g$ is continuous on $[1, 2]$ if $\lim_{x'\to x} g(x') = g(x)$ for all $x\in [1, 2]$. Here, $g$ has been defined at $x = 1$ and $x = 2$ such that this is true, based on the information you've provided about the limits of $f$ at $1$ and $2$.